# How to exit after starting a service in Linux for loop

Tags: linux, bash

I have a for loop I'm using to stop and start number of development servers here is an example.

```
for i in `cat hosts` ; do ssh $i -i .ssh/key.key -t sudo /etc/init.d/jboss-as start ; done
```

This will connect to each box one by one and stop the service, and I have to wait for operation of shutting down a service in this case "jboss" before the connection is made to the other boxes.

Is there is a way that I could excute the request and exit without waiting for it to complete?

Thank you

Comment: Use mussh http://sourceforge.net/projects/mussh/

Comment: I have just tried it, and I like what I'm seeing, great!

Comment: What about the `&` flag to run the command in background so that you can continue with others directive, whithout waiting for the previous one to finish ?

Answer (score 0):

ansible -i hosts -k -m service -a "name=jboss-as state=started"

This is what orchestration-tools are for ;)

Answer (score 0):

As krisFR suggested, run all commands in background:

```
for i in $(cat hosts); do
    (ssh ${i} -i .ssh/key.key -t sudo /etc/init.d/jboss-as start) & 
done
```

NOTE: $() preferred over `` for running a subshell.